# Efficient way to get top 5 rows with max value without using order by?

Tags: sql, database, performance

A Relational database table holds the information of Insurance details, say id and amount. Table consists of millions of records. requirement is to fetch top 5 records with max amount **without** using **order by** clause.

A solution I could think of is to use the temp table to maintain the max 5 records and update these entries each time the main table is updated but would like to know if there are better solution to above problem ?

Comment: Who's requirement? (Manager or teacher?)

Comment: There's no easy way. Indexing might speed up as Gordon said, although there's still ORDER BY and the index overhead. But it might be more efficient than your solution, probably based on triggers: If you update or delete a row with one of the top 5 values you have to run a similar TOP Select again. How often do you query for those top rows, is it really worth implementing it?`

Comment: this is for a POC to improve the query performance and this will be queried very often.

Comment: Do ORDER BY, have an index.

Answer (score 0):

An efficient way is to put an index on `amount desc` and use `order by`.  Something like:

```
select t.*
from t
order by t.amount desc
fetch first 5 rows only;  -- or however your database does this
```

This should be quite efficient.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using analytic functions (example below), but you still have to order at some stage

```
select id,
       amount
from (select id,
             amount,
             row_number() over (order by amount desc nulls last) as rn
      from t)
where rn<=5;
```